# SATA hard disk not recognized

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk, dmesg, sata

there seems to be a problem with the hard disk. I just wanted to know if I can fix it somehow or I should throw it away. the problem is that the hard disk is not recognized.

https://pastebin.com/2BzytHdC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Check SATA cable. Change it if possible.
2. Try another SATA port, if possible.

If none of these action solve the problem, then your hard drive is probably dead:

```
[ 2211.157208] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2211.157211] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[ 2211.157214] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2211.157216] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2211.157218] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
```

Comment: I tried both things, unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: RIP hard drive disk :-(